# Java mockito how to have SXSSFWorkbook purposely throw an error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a piece of code such that:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    ... methods and building sheet
    
    wb.write(fos)
    fos.flush()
    fos.close()
    wb.dispose()
    wb.close()

} catch (IOException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    ...methods here
}
```

Is there a way to purposely have Mockito cause the workbook to throw an error so that when I call this method in JUnit, it returns what is in the catch statement?

Comment: You can pass some invalid path to FileOutPutStream that should throw  
`FileNotFoundException` which is child class `IOException` 

`fos = new FileOutputStream("SomeNonExistentPath");`

You can't use mockito here, since we can't mock `FileOutputStream`

Comment: @HariHaravelan i thought we could use mockito to do a when(fos.close).then(throw exception) for fos.close() but it did nothing

Comment: Mocking doesn't work for those objects created inside the method scope 
mocking only works with the injected objects
@userwithquestions